# Kill this clamd process running from another user which I never know about

Tags: server, malware, clamav, kill, killall

[From HTOP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8udjr.png)

Hi, there is a clamd process running from a user called "tcpdump" I google and found that it's not quite a real user, so I remove that user. However, this process still running and restart itself every time I kill it. Is it a real ClamAV?, and how can I completely remove it. It uses all of my computer ram.

Comment: "so I remove that user" why? FYI: Linux uses users to be able to set permissions to perform tasks that require elevated permissions. If you want to delete such a user you delete the corresponding software. "and how can I completely remove it." remove the software it belongs to? "It uses all of my computer ram." so?  RAM not used is RAM wasted. "Is it a real ClamAV?," what do you mean by that? I would suggest to remove clamav if you have that installed. I have never seen it report a legitimate virus on Linux and that software will ask a lot from your machine.

Comment: I removed that user because I never create that user and it's not called ClamAV as the real one should be. On why not remove the software, because I tried to su to that user and 1.) I can't login there is an error I forget what it's saying, 2.) apt don't recognize it as installed, and  3.) I try to follow the path of in the htop and I cloudn't find that execution file.

Comment: I'm able to solve this issue turn out docker container I pull from docker-mailserver was the one causing this problem, so I shut it down, and all the problem solved.